# How to convert single precision floats saved as tinyblob back to single floats in MySql?

Tags: mysql, matlab, floating-point, blob

In my MySQL table I have a field named `A` of type `tinyblob`. Data in every row is as long as 8 bytes. In these 8 bytes I store sequentially two single numbers.

This is how I convert these two numbers in Matlab:

`typecast(reshape(single([1 8]),[],1),'uint8');`

Now I want to query some rows from my table using these `tinyblob`'s fields.

Therefore, my question is: how do I cast first 4 bytes of this field into a *single(float)* number so that I could use this number in queries?

So, I would expect something like this:

```
select * from table where first_4_bytes_of_A_to_single(A)> 10
```

?

I tried to use `cast` function. But either I'm using it wrong or this function is used for different purposes?

Would this be possible?

Thank you